# Opening messages from windows search opens Outlook instead of Thunderbird

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, windows-search

I'm using TB as my primary client, but still have Outlook installed. Mailto links etc opens TB, but when opening a message indexed by windows search, it opens Outlook instead. I've changed associated files to TB for .msg etc, but still Outlook opens for messages and contacts.

Is there a way to change this so windows search also uses TB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops.. Ignore this. I had indexed Outlook mails too, so each item showed two times - once for outlook and once for TB. I had opened the outlook indexed files...